# ActionForm redirect

Tags: java, struts, forward, actionform

Good afternoon in my timezone.

I am using struts in the development of an enterprise web application,and what i need is very simple to ask.
In the ActionForm, if the validate method returns a non-empty ActionError object the flow is forward to the element that was declared in the input attribute in the struts-config.xml file.
In my case i am not fullfilling the ActionError object with the validation errors , i am using another approach, and i am appending the errors on the request scope.My question is, how can i redirect or forward the flow to the the element that is defined in the input attribute with the ActionError object empty ?
P.S -> I know that i can fullfill the ActionError object with dummy data just to force the redirect to the input element , but i thing that is a poor design.

With the best regards.
Thansk in advance.

Comment: might I ask why you are using struts 1 for a new application (if it even is a new application).  Struts 1 has been phased out long age.  If this is not a company limitation, I highly suggest using struts 2 or spring MVC

Answer (score 0):

```
if (hasSomeError(request)) {
    return mapping.getInputForward();
}
```

See http://struts.apache.org/1.2.9/api/org/apache/struts/action/ActionMapping.html#getInputForward%28%29